# VirtualBox Windows has USB driver but Ubuntu Host does not

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, virtualbox, usb, drivers

My Virtualbox windows XP has drivers for USB device. 
But since Ubuntu host does not have the drivers, does not recognise the device, the virtual windows XP also cannot access them.

The device which I want within XP is shown as "Unknown" in ubuntu (thats ok). But, in the Devices->USB devices menu, I cannot activate it because it is shown as "Status: unavailable"

Is there a way to solve this problem.

Thanks,
Vikas

Answer (score 2):

If Ubuntu ships with the OSE version of VirtualBox it will not include usb drivers. You need to download the Oracle version at

http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

Comment: I already downloaded and use VirtualBox.Ubuntu won't have usb drivers. those are only available for winxp

Comment: did you use apt-get to download or from the link i put? they are two very different versions of VirtualBox

Comment: The device which I want within XP is shown as "Unknown" in ubuntu. Also, in the Devices->USB devices menu, I cannot activate it because it is shown as "Status: unavailable"